# Software Source stops working when changing release name in the lsb_release file

Tags: linux-mint

Software source stops working when changing release name. I am on Linux Mint 10 Julia and when I change the 2 lines in the gksu gedit /etc/*release

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_CODENAME=julia
```

All the rest I can change no problem,what do I have to change in software sources for it to accept them and for the program to work..?

I am making a customized version of Commodore OS 32-bit,adding this and that before releasing it. site is here http://cbmosvision.webs.com/ if you want to look.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Mint.. what is "software source"?

Comment: @drs Software Sources is an application that allows you to modify your repository list.

Answer (score 1):

The files you've changed have are used by the `lsb_release` utility.  See `man lsb_release`.

Mint uses it's own System-Settings plugin called `mintsources` to configure software sources.

If you look in `/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py` you'll see that it uses `lsb_release` to get the distro name.

If you change it to 'Commodore OS' then `mintsources` will be confused.  While you could hack `mintsources` to always use 'LinuxMint' regardless of what `lsb_release` says, it will always be a 'hack' and may cause pain further down the line. (I believe Linux Mint did something similar with Ubuntu `software-center` a while ago to get around similar issues)

Comment: Software Sources are where you can tick or untick your repositories,Oh and I didn't suggest a way of upgrading..?? confused here..?? Right what happens I change the name of the OS from LinuxMint to Commodore OS and you go to System --> Administration --> Software Sources it don't come up nothing,i change it back and its working again.. picture of Software Sources http://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/helena/mintupdate-software-sources.png I am still learning how to use Linux so be gentle..;)

Comment: Sorry - I miss-understood your question. I've edited my answer now, so hopefully it's more relevant.